# Get Intent Value in RASA Core/NLU

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Greeting
I am working on RASA chatbot. I am handling Custom actions for a particular intent using below code. In the custom action I want to get current intent value. SO i dont know that line of code which can give me value of current intent

```
#this file will be used to all custom actions

from  __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
import json
from zeep import Client


from random import randint
from rasa_core.actions.action import Action
from rasa_core.events import SlotSet

class ActionWeather(Action):


RANDOMIZE = False

@staticmethod
def required_fields():
    return [
        EntityFormField("period", "period"),
        EntityFormField("product", "product")
    ]


def name(self):
    return 'action_weather'

def run(self,dispatcher, tracker, domain):

    #Get Slot values
    loc = tracker.get_slot('period')
    pro = tracker.get_slot('product')
    custname= tracker.get_slot('custName')

    #Here I want to get Intent Values as well same like slot value in above code  
    #  So what is code for getting intent value



    #make json
    data = {}
    data['period'] = loc
    data['product'] = pro



    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    jsonobj= json.loads(json_data)


    #code for SOAP
    client = Client('my webservice URL/testsoap?wsdl')
    result = client.service.getData(json_data)
    print('**********************')
    print(result)
    print('#######################')
    jsonobj= json.loads(result)


    #print(response.content)
    #json_response = response.json()
    #print (json_response)
    result1=jsonobj[0]['result']
    #result1=randint(1, 100)
    #result='X'
    response = """sale is {} """.format(result1)
    dispatcher.utter_message(response)
    #return [SlotSet('location',loc)]
    return []
```

I want to get current and last value of intent in RASA Core in same way as we can get slots value `product = tracker.get_slot('product')` in python custom action code. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def run(self,dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    intent =  tracker.latest_message['intent'].get('name')
```

rasa-core           0.11.12
rasa-core-sdk       0.11.5
rasa-nlu            0.13.7

Answer (score 1):

```
intent = json.dumps(tracker.latest_message.intent)
print(intent)
#particular intent name
print(json.loads(intent)['intent']['name'])
```

outcome
(u'{"confidence": 0.9092543377510975, "name": "greet"}')

or try this

```
        intent = json.dumps(tracker.latest_message.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below,

currentIntent = tracker.latest_message.intent["name"]