# Get the user's value of an intent in RASA Core/NLU

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have the same question as in: [Get Intent Value in RASA Core/NLU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645905/get-intent-value-in-rasa-core-nlu/53428985#53428985)
but I want the value that the user gives for a given intent.

For example:

```
User: I want to take it (this sentence is an intent called: 'use_it')
Bot: ....
User: .... (Later in the chat I decide to answer with the same phrase of intent 'use it') 
Bot: you said previously "I want to take it"
```

How can I do something like: `tracker.get_slot` but for intent?

I don't want the name of the last intent I want the text of a user-given intent.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/#custom-actions) after the intent in which you store the intent text in a slot:

```
from rasa_core_sdk import Action
from rasa_core_sdk.events import SlotSet

class ActionStoreIntentMessage(Action):
    """Stores the bot use case in a slot"""

    def name(self):
        return "action_store_intent_message"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

        # we grab the whole user utterance here as there are no real entities
        # in the use case
        message = tracker.latest_message.get('text')

        return [SlotSet('intent_message', message)]
```

You can then use the value of the set slot within an [utter template](https://rasa.com/docs/core/responses/#including-the-utterances-in-the-domain):

```
slots:
  intent_message:
    type: text

templates:
  utter_last_intent:
    - "you said previously: {intent_message}"
```

Comment: I get this error by doing this : AttributeError: 'UserUttered' object has no attribute 'get' will give more details in a message

Comment: I have changed  tracker.latest_message.get('text') with  tracker.latest_message.text and now I'am getting:  NameError: name 'SlotSet' is not defined

Comment: Solved the last one () I just forgot to import SoltSet. My final issue is that the bot recognise the 'intent_message' slot but when I use it in a template it does not show. It shows:  you said previously: {intent_message}                         Any help please?

Comment: My work arround is to add another costum action after saving the new slot. In the second costum action, I do something like:' message = tracker.get_slot('intent_message')  response =  """you said previously: {} """.format(loc)  dispatcher.utter_message(response)'

Comment: I added the imports and the slot definition to my example. Should work now this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tracker for the task.

```
text=tracker.latest_message['text']
```